# How to put input statement inside a print function?

Tags: python, printing

This is the code I did;

```
print("Enter the letter of package( A, B, C)")
input(": ")
```

The output of this will be like this;

```
Enter the letter of package( A, B, C)
: A
```

I need to make the output look like this;

```
Enter the letter of package·(A,·B,·C): A
```

Comment: `input('Enter the letter of package( A, B, C): ')`?

Answer (score 3):

You can just put the printed string inside the `input()` function:

```
input("Enter the letter of package( A, B, C): ")
```

Answer (score 2):

> Python’s print() function comes with a parameter called ‘end‘. By default, the value of this parameter is ‘\n’, i.e. the new line character.

We can change it to whatever use-case we have:

```
print("Enter the letter of package( A, B, C)",end="")
input(": ")
```

Also it will be better if you store your input in a variable for later usage.